# Using Riverpod in Flutter, is it possible to initialize FamilyAsyncNotifier with a value?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I really like Riverpod 2.0's AsyncNotifier. It's great for automatically fetching data from a server as soon as it's referenced. However I've run into an issue, specifically with the family modifier.

For example, a user would have many posts. I'd like the posts provider to be a FamilyAsyncNotifier so it will automatically fetch the post when that post is directly viewed and not cached yet.

The catch is, say you visit a user's page (or see a list of posts in any way such as search/feed/etc), then there's one call to the server to get a list of posts with their data. But now if I reference the post FamilyAsyncNotifier with the post ID, it will try and fetch the post on initialization.

Is there a way to initialize the post with data (in the build method?) so it doesn't fetch the data that we already have from our list of posts? Or am I thinking about this wrong and there's a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AsyncNotifier`, we initialise the value of `AsyncNotifier` by returning the value in the build method and you can also handle the initialisation logic here.

```dart
@riverpod
class PostController extends _$PostController {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<Post>> build({
    required int userId,
  }) {
    // let say you have a cachedPostsProvider
    // you can check if there are already user's posts in the cache
    final cachedPosts = ref.watch(cachedPostsProvider);
    final userPosts = cachedPosts.where((post) => post.userId == userId).toList();
    if (existingPosts.isNotEmpty) {
      return userPosts;
    }
    else {
      // fetch from network
      return ...;
    }
  }
}
```